# Issue with iframe kendo editor change event and external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, kendo-ui, asp-classic

I have an iFrame with kendo editor control that has 'change' event set up. The iFrame is ran within old asp page that has some action buttons with 'onChange' events set up. When I type in some text within my kendo editor (iFrame) and then click directly on my asp action button, the kendo change even does not get fired (only asp button onChange event code does).

How can I make sure that in my case (iFrame with kendo control + asp page), the kendo editor change event will always get fired if I click anywhere both on my iFrame and on my asp page area (including action buttons)?

Answer (score 0):

adding "async: false" to kendo control seems to be fixing the issue.